# Convert utf-8 to iso-8859-2 (polish)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, utf-8, iso-8859-2

I have some problems downloading data event from facebook.
I have a site ,`add.php`, - this site is `UTF-8`, next I'm sending a data to `mysql` (`utf-8`) and then I'm displaying information on website (`iso-8859-2`).
Problem is when I'm displaying this data there are no polish signs.

How can I convert this data to `iso-8859-2` like on original event facebook page?

I was trying `iconv` but it doesn't work:

```
function utf2iso( $tekst ) {
  iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $tekst );
  return $tekst;
  };
```

`Iconv` doesn't works, please help - give me some advice!

PS. Sorry for my english :-)

Comment: Why not in html set the charset  `<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">`

Comment: website have a charset iso-8859-2, i can download and send to database data in utf-8 but i cant convert to iso-8859-2 and display with polish signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iconv()** returns converted text or false, but doesn't modify reference

```
function utf2iso( $tekst ) {
    return iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $tekst );
};
```